# Angular JS Material mdMedia seems to be not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I do have a toolbar

```
<md-toolbar layout="row">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-button ng-click="mainCtrl.toggleSidenav('left')" ng-hide="$mdMedia('min-width: 16cm')"
               class="md-icon-button">
        <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg">
        </md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

The problem is with "'min-width: 16cm'"

I do have similar problems within a sidenav (with "ng-show="$mdMedia('max-width: 300px')") as well.

In the toolbar the button should vanish if the width is larger than 16cm. The button in the sidenav should only be visible if the with is smaller than 300.

The problem is the following: Either it is visible or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

mdMedia was not referenced in the scope ([Issue on Github](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2341#issuecomment-93680762)).

So

```
$scope.$mdMedia = $mdMedia;
```

was all it needed ;)